# mapping user-space to kernel-space memory using shm_open & mmap

Tags: c, linux, kernel

What i'm trying to do is that, i want to create a shared memory in user space, then i send the name of this shared memory & its size to a custom system call, then this system call open this shared memory & modify it. using `shm_open` & `mmap`. is that possible to do between user space & kernel space ?

My problem is that

Whenever i try to `make` to the new custom kernel i got the following errors

- Implicit declaration of shm_open & mmap
- PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE etc...

Here are the included header files

- `unistd.h` `stdlib` `sys/types` `sys/stat` `sys/shm` `sys/mman` `fcntl` & other headers.

in gcc i would invoke this command `gcc example.c -lrt` & it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html), you need:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
```

in your file. Specifically `<sys/stat.h>` contains the missing constants. Perhaps you are missing `.h`.

If that does not help, I suggest you post a minimal example illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever i try to `make` to the new custom kernel i got the following
>   errors
>
> - Implicit declaration of shm_open & mmap

*Library functions* like `shm_open` and `mmap` aren't to be used from *kernel* code.
You might want to look at an implementation of [`shm_open`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/glibc-2_1_93/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/shm_open.c#117), but note that there for example the library function `open` is used, for which the above applies; in your kernel code you would use e. g. [`do_sys_open`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/open.c#L1068) instead.